# @ngrx/store does not works on ng serve -prod

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

NgRx works well on serve in development mode `ng serve`, but when serve in prod mode `ng serve -prod` or buid `ng build --prod` ngrx does not works more.

[example app repo](https://github.com/ThompsonMatiasF/Angular-and-NgRx-Trouble)

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs for NGRX state. This is the proper format to handle the AOT build issue you are seeing.

"Previously to be AOT compatible, it was required to pass a function to the provideStore method to compose the reducers into one root reducer. The initialState was also provided to the method as an object in the second argument."

"This has been simplified to only require a map of reducers that will be composed together by the library. A second argument is a configuration object where you provide the initialState."

Their example looks as follows reducer `index.ts`:

```
import { ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';

export interface State {
  auth: fromAuth.State;
  layout: fromLayout.State;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
  auth: fromAuth.reducer,
  layout: fromLayout.reducer,
};
```

And in your `app.module`:

```
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { reducers } from './reducers';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
      initialState: {
        auth: {
          loggedIn: true,
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I think your code is missing the initial state declaration that allows the AOT compilation engine to properly identify what you are trying to define on build.

Comment: Anthony, I dont have StoreModule.provideStore() method, @ngrx/store version on my project: 5.2.0